# How to send given p12 file in post request using java.net.HttpURLConnection (Two way Handshake p12 cert file)

Tags: java, ssl, keystore, pkcs#12, p12

I need to send .p12 file to communicate client-server to send the post request JSON and get the response. I am pretty new to these cert  p12 files authentication. Through postman using the p12 file am able to get the response. Now I am trying through the application

```
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
            keyStore.load(new FileInputStream("/path/newKeyStoreFileName.jks"), keystorepwd.toCharArray());
            KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            kmf.init(keyStore, keystorepwd.toCharArray());
            KeyManager[] kms = kmf.getKeyManagers();
            SSLContext  sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            sslContext.init(kms, null, new SecureRandom());
```

Comment: You need to use the data in a p12 file or equivalent to do 'two-way' TLS (more accurately mutual authentication or client authentication) but that does _not_ send the p12 file. You show nerarly correct code to read the file into a context (you leak the open, which could cause failures later) but you don't show how and if you use this context, so this is not a reproducible example and it's impossible to help you.

Comment: did u figure it out  i keep getting 500 error while its working fine with curl or postman